# NullReferenceException When Using VerifyHashedPassword in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Here's what happen i am working on login controller where i need to verify user input password with password hash that is in the database. When i'm trying to verify the correct password it is returning NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. But when i debug it, the line with this code :

```
var verified = hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(inputModel, resultData.passwordhash, password);
```

is skipped and does not executed but when i return the value of verified.toString() directly after calling above line of code, it is printing a "Success" string. But when it is failed to verify, the code just work properly. Here's the full code :

```
public dbSearchResponse dbSearch(string username, string password, ADResponse ldapResult)
        {
            LoginResponse finalResult = new LoginResponse();
            TableSystemUser resultData = new TableSystemUser();

            PasswordHasher<OldLoginParamModel> hasher = new PasswordHasher<OldLoginParamModel>(
                new OptionsWrapper<PasswordHasherOptions>(
                new PasswordHasherOptions()
                {
                    CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2
                }));

            OldLoginParamModel inputModel = new OldLoginParamModel();
            inputModel.grant_type = "password";
            inputModel.password = password;
            inputModel.username = username;

            string hashedPassword = hasher.HashPassword(inputModel, inputModel.password);

            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(configuration.GetValue<string>("dbServer:connectionData")))
            {
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    var value = connection.Query<TableSystemUser>(
                        "SELECT id, email, emailconfirmed, passwordhash, phonenumber, username, fullname, dateofbirth, gender, COALESCE(usercredit.saldo, 0) as saldo, pricing.psc, pricing.psm, pricing.plc, pricing.plm, pricing.csc, pricing.csm, pricing.clc, pricing.clm, pricing.ssc, pricing.ssm, pricing.slc, pricing.slm FROM systemuser LEFT OUTER JOIN usercredit ON systemuser.id = usercredit.systemuserid INNER JOIN userpricing ON UUID(systemuser.id) = userpricing.systemuserid INNER JOIN pricing ON userpricing.pricingid = pricing.pricingid WHERE systemuser.email= '" + username + "' and systemuser.emailconfirmed = true;"
                        );
                    resultData = value.First();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Failed response
                    dbSearchResponse dbRespNRErr = new dbSearchResponse();
                    dbRespNRErr.loginResponse = null;
                    dbRespNRErr.userid = null;
                    dbRespNRErr.response = "Email not registered.";
                    return dbRespNRErr;
                }
            }

            var verified = hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(inputModel, resultData.passwordhash, password);

           /*But when return the verified.toString() value here, it is returning "Success"
            dbSearchResponse dbRespErr = new dbSearchResponse();
            dbRespErr.loginResponse = null;
            dbRespErr.userid = null;
            dbRespErr.response = verified.toString();
            return dbRespErr; */

            if (verified.toString() == "Success")
            {
                finalResult.FullName = resultData.fullname;
                finalResult.Gender = resultData.gender;
                //11/26/1998 12:00:00 AM
                finalResult.DateOfBirth = resultData.dateofbirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
                finalResult.Phone = resultData.phonenumber;
                finalResult.Email = resultData.email;
                finalResult.UserName = resultData.username;
                finalResult.PLC = resultData.plc.ToString();
                finalResult.PLM = resultData.plm.ToString();
                finalResult.PSC = resultData.psc.ToString();
                finalResult.PSM = resultData.psm.ToString();
                finalResult.SLC = resultData.slc.ToString();
                finalResult.SLM = resultData.slm.ToString();
                finalResult.SSC = resultData.ssc.ToString();
                finalResult.SSM = resultData.ssm.ToString();
                finalResult.CLC = resultData.clc.ToString();
                finalResult.CLM = resultData.clm.ToString();
                finalResult.CSC = resultData.csc.ToString();
                finalResult.CSM = resultData.csm.ToString();
                finalResult.PayLater = ldapResult.memberof;
                finalResult.Credit = resultData.saldo.ToString();

                dbSearchResponse dbResp = new dbSearchResponse();
                dbResp.loginResponse = finalResult;
                dbResp.userid = resultData.id;
                dbResp.response = "success";

                return dbResp;
            }
            //Failed response
            dbSearchResponse dbRespErr = new dbSearchResponse();
            dbRespErr.loginResponse = null;
            dbRespErr.userid = null;
            dbRespErr.response = "The user name or password is incorrect.";
            return dbRespErr;
        }
```

Anyone know what happen and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked `inputModel` is null or not.

Comment: are you using async, await?

Comment: input model is populated and not null, i've checked that and i'm not using async or await

Comment: Clean, rebuild and retry with setting build mode is debug, not release or put try catch in VerifyHashedPassword and find any exception occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i do some detailed run check, i notice that the null part of the code is,

```
finalResult.PayLater = ldapResult.memberof;
```

But i don't understand why is the error response given suggest that the null was this line of code

```
var verified = hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(inputModel, resultData.passwordhash, password);
```

so in that case, i thanks to everyone who have responded to my question.